Streaming audio over websockets and process it with ffmpeg, Invalid frame size error
I am building an application in Python that processes audio data on a streaming connection with WebSockets. To work with it, I need to process it with ffmpeg on the server before passing it to some ML algorithms.
I have the following ffmpeg code setup to process each byte sequence that comes over WebSockets:
async def ffmpeg_read(bpayload: bytes, sampling_rate: int = 16000) -> np.array:
    ar = f"{sampling_rate}"
    ac = "1"
    format_for_conversion = "f32le"
    ffmpeg_command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", "pipe:0",
        "-ac", ac,
        "-acodec", f"pcm_{format_for_conversion}",
        "-ar", ar,
        "-f", format_for_conversion,
        "pipe:1"]
    try:
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            *ffmpeg_command,
            stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

        process.stdin.write(bpayload)
        await process.stdin.drain() 
        process.stdin.close()

        out_bytes = await process.stdout.read(8000)  # Read asynchronously
        audio = np.frombuffer(out_bytes, np.float32)

        if audio.shape[0] == 0:
            raise ValueError("Malformed soundfile")
        return audio

    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise ValueError(
            "ffmpeg was not found but is required to load audio files from filename")

In every test, this works for exactly one message and prints the desired output to the screen, but the second one gets the following:
[mp3 @ 0x1208051e0] Invalid frame size (352): Could not seek to 363.
[in#0 @ 0x600002214200] Error opening input: Invalid argument
Error opening input file pipe:0.

How do I fix this?

Is your input streamed or output streamed? If it's the former, your function expects the bpayload bytes to be the entire mp3 file, and this is likely culprit. If you're intent is to continuously feed streamed bytes to FFmpeg, don't close the stdin prematurely.

Thanks, that's the correct hunch. Ended up figuring it out, answering below :)

The problem here is that ffmpeg expect the byte sequence to be complete if it's running just once, so subsequent frames were invalid sound files. The solution, like Kesh mentioned above, is to not close stdin.
Using Python's asyncio library, here's a solution I came up with, with generous support from online documentation, the Huggingface transformers library, the Whisper library, and GPT-4:
async def write_to_ffmpeg(input_queue: asyncio.Queue, ffmpeg_input):
    while True:
        data = await input_queue.get()
        if data is None:
        ffmpeg_input.close()
            break
        ffmpeg_input.write(data)  
        await ffmpeg_input.drain() 
   
async def read_from_ffmpeg(ffmpeg_output):
    while True:
        output = ffmpeg_output.read(1024)
        print(output)
 

async def process_websocket(input_queue: asyncio.Queue, sampling_rate=16000):
    ar = f"{sampling_rate}"
    ac = "1"
    format_for_conversion = "f32le"
    ffmpeg_command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", "pipe:0",
        "-ac", ac,
        "-acodec", f"pcm_{format_for_conversion}",
        "-ar", ar,
        "-f", format_for_conversion,
        "pipe:1"]
    ffmpeg_process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *ffmpeg_command,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    writer_task = asyncio.create_task(
        write_to_ffmpeg(input_queue, ffmpeg_process.stdin))
    reader_task = asyncio.create_task(
        read_from_ffmpeg(ffmpeg_process.stdout))

    try:
        await writer_task
        await reader_task
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await ffmpeg_process.kill()
    finally:
        # Wait for the FFmpeg process to terminate
        await ffmpeg_process.wait()

